# Safari 12 Not Showing Javascript Errors

Tags: javascript, safari, console

For some reason, Safari 12 has stopped showing Javascript errors in the console.  Has anyone else experienced this?  I can't find any information about it on the Internet.  Does anyone have a solution or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  Turned out to be an extension causing the problem.